# How does one find a kernel commit from a launchpad bug report?

Tags: kernel, launchpad, source-code

When reviewing the following launchpad kernel bug there is an notice that says it has been committed to the Xenial master-next.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1686099
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1686099/comments/24

When I look at the Ubuntu Xenial kernel source code I don't see that commit.  I'm used to systems that directly link bug reports and commits.  My question is:  What is the process one can use to find a commit from a launchpad bug report?  I understand that it might be different based on the package the fix is in.  I'm just interested in kernel fixes with this question.